Unable to reference a property defined inside a file
On the root folder of the project I created a file named .env containing properties and their associated value :
APP_FRONT_URL=http://localhost:8080
APP_API_URL=http://localhost:8081
APP_SITE_URL=http://localhost:8082
APP_PRINT_URL=http://localhost:5000

Then in the application.properties file I want to reference a property defined in the .env file :
api.url = ${APP_API_URL}/api

But when I tried to run the project then I get error that it could not resolve placeholder 'APP_API_URL'
So how to fix it ?

By default spring / spring boot supports properties configuration defined in .properties file or .yaml file. Ref: External Application Properties
If you want to support any other format of the files, you need to let spring know how the file needs to be interpreted and as its a custom named file the path also needs to be specified.
So in your properties file you can do something like below to solve the problem:
spring.config.import=${folder path to your env file}/.env[.properties]
api.url=${APP_FRONT}/api

the [.properties] will let spring interpret the .env file as a properties file. Reference: Importing Extensionless Files

Correct spring.config.import=file:.env/[.properties] does work.

I get Config data resource 'file [.env]' via location 'file:.env/[.properties]' does not exist
